# How do I redirect all but a single url to https in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, http-redirect

I have the following code in my web.config:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect HTTP to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" 
                    redirectType="SeeOther" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

I would like to redirect everything EXCEPT for http://www.mysite.com/manual to https.

How would I modify the above to allow this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be ok with adding the following code in your conditions tag

```
<add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^/manual/*" ignoreCase="true" />
```